# Post Likes via Graph API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

The Graph API doesn't work and I get error code 100 when post /ID/likes with no parameters like the documentation says.

Can anybody help me? Is this even possible to do as the documentation say? If I try the Graph API Explorer I get the same error.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: _What_ are you trying to like? Some more details, please.

Answer (score 1):

The `likes` connection is for `GET` requests only

> All the pages this user has liked.

You cannot use it to post likes.

You can read the pages that a User has liked by issuing an `HTTP GET` to `/PROFILE_ID/likes` with the `user_likes` or `friends_likes` permissions.

Read more at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

Comment: Yes, the abuse rate would be too high and there would be pages with millions of fans just because of an application which posts the likes.

Answer (score 0):

You can like a Post by issuing a HTTP POST request to the POST_ID/likes connection with the publish_stream permission. No parameters necessary.

If the write is successful, you get the following return.

```
Description         Type
If the like succeeded   boolean
```